# can somebody explain how you get the second line from the first line in the picture?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I'm trying to understand the transition from the 1st line of the Lagrangian to the second. we substitute for $\eta$ but how is the multiplication happening here? if I multiply the terms into the matrix elements, won't I get a matrix whose elements are the terms to the right of the matrix here?[image]

Comment: Recall that repeated indices are summed over. The term $\eta^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi$ is a *scalar*, not a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ is non-zero for diagonal elements only, we only need to sum those terms when $\mu = \nu$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
&\qquad \frac{1}{2} \eta^{\mu \nu} \; \partial_{\mu}\phi \; \partial_{\nu} \phi \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[ \eta^{00} \partial_{0}\phi \; \partial_{0} \phi 
\; + \; \eta^{11} \partial_{1}\phi \; \partial_{1} \phi
\; + \; \eta^{22} \partial_{2}\phi \; \partial_{2} \phi
\; + \; \eta^{33} \partial_{3}\phi \; \partial_{3} \phi
\Bigg]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[ (+1)\partial_{t}\phi \; \partial_{t} \phi 
\; + \; (-1) \partial_{x}\phi \; \partial_{x} \phi
\; + \; (-1) \partial_{y}\phi \; \partial_{y} \phi
\; + \; (-1) \partial_{z}\phi \; \partial_{z} \phi
\Bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \dot{\phi}^{\, 2} - \frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2 
\end{align}